# Does TLS use use two symmetric keys in the same way SSH does? One for client to server and one for server to client communication?

Tags: protocol-design, tls, protocol-analysis, ssh

As described in the [SSH RFC](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc4253) an initial IV to server, initial IV to client, encryption key client to server, encryption key server to client, integrity key client to server, and an integrity key server to client are generated.

Does TLS use a similar system? If not, Why doesn't TLS use a system like this?

Comment: Hi, Which TLS version are you referring to? Or what is the source of this claim. Based on this it seems key separation is done in version 1.2 https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc5246#section-6.3

Comment: Basically dupe https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/1139 (automatically found by SE as 'related' -- did you even look?) and https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/50799

Answer (score 2):

> Why doesn't TLS use a system like this?

TLS *does* have separate client-to-server and server-to-client keys - it always has, and that has not changed in any published version of TLS or SSL.

What makes you think it doesn't?

Comment: [This comment](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/214054).

Comment: Yes it was that comment. Change the title so it hopefully doesn't confuse others.